# (Android) implementing swipe gestures on a collection of objects

Tags: android, android-studio, swipe, swipe-gesture

*** UPDATE  -> the swipe gesture now works (classes "PieceViewFragment" and "OnSwipeTouchListener" have been updated accordingly) , but I would really like to get the nice visual effect (movement) that you get when swipping from one item to the other. Right now it just switches to the next or previous item.**

---

*** NEW UPDATE  -> I was able to get that nice visual effect (movement) that you get when swipping from one item to the other (thanks to Nobby_Nobody's last comment and link).**

get the code here –> [My Project on github](https://github.com/sylvain-gdk/projet-Bracelet/commit/c8b28393cd22c3107f90ffeb2c55dbcd28dd1d85)

---

I need help to implement swiping gesture through a collection of items in an Android personnal project (an inventory list). I've seen tons of examples already but I can't seem to implement it correctly.

The application is simple. It's just an inventory (InventairesPieces) implemented as a scrolling list (InventairesPiecesActivity and InventairesPiecesFragment) of items (PieceModel) and once an item is clicked, the details (PieceViewActivity and PieceViewFragment) open in another activity.

It's in the details activity (PieceViewActivity and PieceViewFragment) that I want to be able to swipe accross items instead of going back to the scrolling list each time.

So far I tried implementing “ViewPager” set to an adapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter on my fragment (PieceViewFragment) but it’s not working properly:

*** when an item is clicked, it shows the first item of the list, no matter which item was clicked. Also the title in the action bar doesn't match. ***

Here's the "PieceViewActivity" class:

```
public class PieceViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InventairePieces inventairePieces;

private PieceModel piece;

private int position;

/**
 * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
 * and next wizard steps.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

/**
 * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
 */
private InventairePiecesPagerAdapter inventairePiecesPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_piece_view);

    // receives the intent
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    inventairePieces = (InventairePieces) intent.getSerializableExtra("inventairePieces");
    position = (int) intent.getSerializableExtra("posClicked");

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    inventairePiecesPagerAdapter = new InventairePiecesPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_piece_view_container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(inventairePiecesPagerAdapter);
}

public class InventairePiecesPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public InventairePiecesPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int posView) {
        return PieceViewFragment.create(posView, position, inventairePieces);
    }

    @Override
    //the amount of items in the inventory
    public int getCount() {
        return inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size();
    }

}
```

}

Here's the "PieceViewFragment" class (the details or card):

```
public class PieceViewFragment extends Fragment {

protected OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener;

private InventairePieces inventairePieces;

private PieceModel piece;

private int positionClicked;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_piece_view, null, false);

    // receives the intent
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    inventairePieces = (InventairePieces) intent.getSerializableExtra("inventairePieces");
    positionClicked = (int) intent.getSerializableExtra("posClicked");
    piece = inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().get(positionClicked);

    // sets the title in the action bar
    getActivity().setTitle(piece.getNomPiece());

    Log.v("Fragment", "Pos Clicked: " + positionClicked);
    Log.v("Fragment" , "Piece: " + piece.getNomPiece());
    Log.v("Fragment", "Inventaire: " + inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size());

    // the item card
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.codePiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf("# " + piece.getCodePiece()));
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nomPiece_text)).setText(piece.getNomPiece());
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPiece_text)).setText(piece.getDescriptionPiece());
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dimensionPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getDimensionPiece()) + " mm");
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prixCoutantPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getPrixCoutantPiece()) + " $");
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qtyPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getQtyPiece()));
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.typePiece_text)).setText(piece.getTypePiece());
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoriePiece_text)).setText(piece.getCategoriePiece());

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()){
        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight();
            Log.v("Fragment", "onSwipeRight - ");
            if (positionClicked > 0) {
                positionClicked--;
                piece = inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().get(positionClicked);

                // sets the title in the action bar
                getActivity().setTitle(piece.getNomPiece());

                // the item card
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.codePiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf("# " + piece.getCodePiece()));
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nomPiece_text)).setText(piece.getNomPiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPiece_text)).setText(piece.getDescriptionPiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dimensionPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getDimensionPiece()) + " mm");
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prixCoutantPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getPrixCoutantPiece()) + " $");
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qtyPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getQtyPiece()));
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.typePiece_text)).setText(piece.getTypePiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoriePiece_text)).setText(piece.getCategoriePiece());

                Log.v("Fragment", "Pos Clicked: " + positionClicked);
                Log.v("Fragment" , "Piece: " + piece.getNomPiece());
                Log.v("Fragment", "Inventaire: " + inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            super.onSwipeLeft();
            Log.v("Fragment", "onSwipeLeft + ");
            if(positionClicked < inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size()-1) {
                positionClicked++;
                piece = inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().get(positionClicked);

                // sets the title in the action bar
                getActivity().setTitle(piece.getNomPiece());

                // the item card
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.codePiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf("# " + piece.getCodePiece()));
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nomPiece_text)).setText(piece.getNomPiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPiece_text)).setText(piece.getDescriptionPiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dimensionPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getDimensionPiece()) + " mm");
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prixCoutantPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getPrixCoutantPiece()) + " $");
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qtyPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getQtyPiece()));
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.typePiece_text)).setText(piece.getTypePiece());
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoriePiece_text)).setText(piece.getCategoriePiece());

                Log.v("Fragment", "Pos Clicked: " + positionClicked);
                Log.v("Fragment" , "Piece: " + piece.getNomPiece());
                Log.v("Fragment", "Inventaire: " + inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size());
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Here the new OnSwipeTouchListener class that handles gestures:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context c) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(c, new GestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // Determines the fling velocity and then fires the appropriate swipe event accordingly
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeDown();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeUp() {
}

public void onSwipeDown() {
}
```

}

And here's the "InventairesPiecesFragment" class from where you click on an item in a scrolling list:

```
public class InventairePiecesFragment extends Fragment{

private ArrayAdapter<PieceModel> inventairePiecesAdapter;

private InventairePieces inventairePieces;

private PieceModel piece;

private Bundle bundle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) container.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PieceEditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("piece", piece);
            intent.putExtra("inventairePieces", inventairePieces);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    inventairePieces = new InventairePieces(new ArrayList<PieceModel>());
    this.readInventairePiece();

    inventairePiecesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.liste_pieces_inventaire,
            R.id.liste_pieces_inventaire_textview,
            inventairePieces.getInventairePieces());

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pieces_inventaire, container, false);

    ListView inventairePiecesAdapterView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_pieces_inventaire);
    inventairePiecesAdapterView.setAdapter(inventairePiecesAdapter);

    inventairePiecesAdapterView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            piece = inventairePiecesAdapter.getItem(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PieceViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("inventairePieces", inventairePieces);
            intent.putExtra("posClicked", i);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            Log.v("short clicked","pos: " + i);
        }
    });
    inventairePiecesAdapterView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long id) {
            piece = inventairePiecesAdapter.getItem(i);
            ConfirmeSuppDialogFragment dialogFrag = new ConfirmeSuppDialogFragment();
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("piece",piece);
            bundle.putSerializable("inventairePieces",inventairePieces);
            dialogFrag.setArguments(bundle);
            dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(InventairePiecesFragment.this, 2);
            dialogFrag.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

            Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + i);

            return true;
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    this.writeInventairePiece();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 1) {
        piece = (PieceModel) data.getSerializableExtra("piece");
        inventairePieces.addToInventairePieces(piece);
        this.writeInventairePiece();
        inventairePiecesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        printConfirmerState(piece, "ajoutée");
    }
    else if(resultCode == 2){
        inventairePieces.removeFromInventairePieces(piece);
        this.writeInventairePiece();
        inventairePiecesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        printConfirmerState(piece, "supprimée");
    }
}

private void writeInventairePiece(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputFile = this.getContext().openFileOutput("InventairePiece.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.writeObject(inventairePieces);
        outputStream.close();
        outputFile.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readInventairePiece(){
    try {
        FileInputStream inputFile = this.getContext().openFileInput("InventairePiece.ser");
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputFile);
        inventairePieces = (InventairePieces) inputStream.readObject();
        inputStream.close();
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void printConfirmerState(PieceModel piece, String state){
    String confirm = state;
    for(int i = 0; i < inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size(); i++) {
        if(i == inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().indexOf(piece) && state.equals("ajoutée")) {
            confirm = ("La pièce '" + piece.getNomPiece() + "' est " + state + ".");
        }else if(i == inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().indexOf(piece) && state.equals("supprimée")) {
            confirm = ("La pièce '" + piece.getNomPiece() + "' est " + state + ".");
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), confirm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


/*@Override
public void updateResult(int result) {
    this.result = result;
}*/
```

}

I thank you in advance.

And just in case, here's the full application as I have it so far:
[My Project on gitHub](https://github.com/sylvain-gdk/projet-Bracelet.git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also able to implement the swipe gesture using ViewPager and an inner class extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

It wasn't that complicated in the end but I really struggled to make it work in the beginning, that's why I'm sharing that code as well, hoping it can help someone eventually. Get the code here –> [My Project on github](https://github.com/sylvain-gdk/projet-Bracelet/commit/e61486f723a418a1e27846d963120a4d8e34a5ee)

Here are the two classes that these changes affected:

PieceViewActivity:

```
public class PieceViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments representing
     * each object in a collection. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will destroy and re-create fragments as needed, saving and restoring their
     * state in the process. This is important to conserve memory and is a best practice when
     * allowing navigation between objects in a potentially large collection.
     */
    PieceViewPagerAdapter pieceViewPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.ViewPager} that will display the object collection.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_piece_view);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.activity_piece_view_container, new PieceViewFragment())
                    .commit();

            // Create an adapter that when requested, will return a fragment representing an object in
            // the collection.
            pieceViewPagerAdapter = new PieceViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_piece_view_container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(pieceViewPagerAdapter);

            //Receives the position of the item peviously clicked in the inventory list
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(intent.getIntExtra("posClicked", -1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter} that returns a fragment
     * representing an object in the collection.
     */
    public class PieceViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        //Accesses the InventairePieces class
        private InventairePieces inventairePieces;

        public PieceViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            inventairePieces = (InventairePieces) intent.getSerializableExtra("inventairePieces");
        }

        /**
         * Gets the item position on swipe gestures
         * sends the detail fragment in a bundle
         * @param position the item position from swipe gesture
         * @return the new fragment details
         */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new PieceViewFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the size of the inventory from an intent
         * @return the size of the inventory
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size();
        }
    }
}
```

PieveViewFragment:

```
public class PieceViewFragment extends Fragment {

    //Accesses the InventairePieces class
    private InventairePieces inventairePieces;
    //Accesses the PieceModel class
    private PieceModel piece;
    //The object's position in the inventory list
    private int positionClicked;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //Gets the inventory from an intent
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        positionClicked = intent.getIntExtra("posClicked", -1);
        inventairePieces = (InventairePieces) intent.getSerializableExtra("inventairePieces");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_piece_view, container, false);

        //Gets the item position from a bundle
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        if(args != null) {
            positionClicked = args.getInt("position");
            piece = inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().get(positionClicked);

            //Sets the object's details
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.invCount_text)).setText(String.valueOf("(" + (positionClicked + 1) + "/" + inventairePieces.getInventairePieces().size()) + ")");
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.codePiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf("# " + piece.getCodePiece()));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nomPiece_text)).setText(piece.getNomPiece());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionPiece_text)).setText(piece.getDescriptionPiece());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dimensionPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getDimensionPiece()) + " mm");
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prixCoutantPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getPrixCoutantPiece()) + " $");
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qtyPiece_text)).setText(String.valueOf(piece.getQtyPiece()));
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.typePiece_text)).setText(piece.getTypePiece());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoriePiece_text)).setText(piece.getCategoriePiece());
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got it right, you have a list of items right? and whenever you select any item you're showing an Activity with all the details of that item (PieceModel); and you want to implement a gesture recognizer in this fragment to switch between the previous and next item without having to go back to the list and select the new item tight?.

If my understanding is good you can do it like this:

1. Implement a gesture recognizer to handle the left and right swipes over the fragment.
2. Depending on gesture you get the new item object (PieceModel) from the data source you're using also when you create your list adapter, and update the current instance stored in your fragment.
3. Update the UI using this "new" item as if the fragment has been loaded from scratch.

And voila!!!, some links here :

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

http://guides.codepath.com/android/gestures-and-touch-events

By the way, when you pass the index of the selected item to the new Activity you should retrieve it as :

```
position = getIntent().getIntExtra("posClicked");
```

I highly recommend you to pass the item Id instead the position, by the way, is InventairePieces implementing the Serializable interface?

Comment: Thanks for the links and recommendations. I'll have a look tonight. You understood everything and InventairePieces is in fact implementing serializable. I already implemented ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter in the fragment but something is not working properly.

Comment: *<<By the way, when you pass the index of the selected item to the new Activity you should retrieve it as : position = getIntent().getIntExtra("posClicked"); >>*   But that would require a default value as: position = getIntent().getIntExtra("posClicked", defaultIntValue);

Comment: I don't think implementing a ViewPager to switch between items is a good idea; Even if Android recycle every Pager view you are doing a lot of work just to switch between Items (Imagine you have hundreds of items in your data source); about the call to the _**getIntExtra()**_ method, you just need to add any default value, lets say -1; if after getting the value the _**position**_ variable is -1 you'll know that something went wrong and you can handle the error gracefully

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. I was starting to doubt about the ViewPager approach... seems it might be more suitable for swiping accross fragments. I'm testing your approach as I'm writing.

Comment: Ok, so I finally managed to make the swipe gesture work (thanks to you) except that I don't get the nice visual when swipping from one item to the other. Would you know how to get that? (note: I updated the class "PieceViewFragment")

Comment: You can add the animations if you want the fancy slide in/out transition; You just need to create the XML files and apply them whenever you are changing the item being displayed. Some info here : https://kylewbanks.com/blog/left-and-right-slide-animations-on-android-activity-or-view